# Heroku not syncing with SalesForce when I change values in postegres trigger

Tags: postgresql, heroku, salesforce

I am using heroku connect to sync My data with salesforce.
I need to change a field in a column after the data is synced.
SO I created a trigger after insert in postegressql that will change that column value. The problem is that when I change the value in the trigger, Heroku is not considering that a change has happened so the data is not synced.

to clarify I have an object in sales force with column name isInsertedInHeroku. By default it is false. in the postegres after insert I am changing it to true but this value is not changing in salesforce, any idea?
this is my trigger.
Please note that I already added the externalId field and when I manually update the value with an update query it will change. this is not working only when I change thru trigger.

```
BEGIN 
UPDATE salesforce.notification__c 
set isInsertedInHeroku= true
where sfid = new.sfid;
Return new;
end;
```